# How run JavaScript function when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I have a set of `grid boxes` that when i switch `color pallet` to a particular color, on `mouse hover` it should change to that color and when i click the `rgb button` the random color should override the color pallet that was first initialized.
But rbg button is displaying `null` because its outside of `drawGrid()` function

So the issue I am having is how to make both work at a different interval, whenever `rbg button` is clicked it should override the `color pallet`  and vice versa.

```js
function drawGrid(container, col, row) {
  const box = document.createElement('div');
  box.className = 'box';
  box.id = `box${col}${row}`;

  // Wehn color pallet is clicked mouseenter radom colors and it should ignore rbg button
  const bgColor = document.querySelector('#bg-color');
  box.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  box.style.backgroundColor = bgColor.value;
  });

  container.appendChild(box);
  return (box);
}


function createBox(container) {
  const grid = document.createElement('div');
  grid.className = 'grid';

  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      drawGrid(grid, i, j);
    }
  }
  container.appendChild(grid);
}

function startupGrid() {
  const game = document.querySelector('#game');
  createBox(game)
}
startupGrid()

// Wehn rbg button is clicked mouseenter random colors and it should ignore color pallet
const rgb = document.querySelector('#rgb');
rgb.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let switchToRgb = `rgb ${r},${g},${b}`;
  box.style.backgroundColor = switchToRgb;
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  place-items: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  margin: 5rem;
}

.controls {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

button {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}


#game {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  
}

.box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  gap: 1px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Grid</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="color" id="bg-color">
      <button id="rgb">RBG</button>
    </div>
     
    <div id="game"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

whereas if i add `box` to the addEventlistener inside `drawGrid()` function instead or `rgb` it works, but then the `color pallet` will stop working.

```
box.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let switchToRgb = `rgb ${r},${g},${b}`;
  box.style.backgroundColor = switchToRgb;
})
```

[image: First image is when color pallet is changed]
[image: Example image]

Comment: Your button has the id `rbg` not `rgb` as your code is expecting

Comment: Also, `rgb` is a CSS function and has it's parameters surrounded by parentheses i.e. `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})` - [link to the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgb)

Comment: Oh thanks, I just edited it. Now box is showing undefined because its outside ```drawGrid()``` function, so i tried adding it inside the function and i didn't receive any error, but the button is not working, is there a way I can call ```drawGrid()``` inside the ```addEventListener``` so that when the button is clicked the random color should display on mousehover

Comment: You don't need to, see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is the format of the color string you want to set the input as, it needs to be the right format `#RRGGBB` [Input color value docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#value)

```
let switchToRgb = `#${r.toString(16)}${g.toString(16)}${b.toString(16)}`;
```

**See update below about properly creating this colour string**

this will create the string in the right format by converting each decimal value to hexadecimal and formatting the string with a leading `#`.

That's right `box` doesn't exist at that point, you will have to get it inside the event listener. You should also set the input's value as this will change the rendered colours in the grid.

```
document.getElementById('bg-color').value = switchToRgb;
```

It strikes me as a bit weird that you're using `mouseenter` event on a button. Why don't you use `click` like most people, this will prevent accidental changes to the colour - FIXED

**UPDATE -** *OP wants to use either a random colour each time the background color is set or use the value from color picker*

You will need to keep track of whether to use a random color or use the color picked value.

```
let useRandomColor = false;
```

We'll default this to false but update it when either a specific colour is picked or the random colour button is clicked.

```
document.getElementById('rgb')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    useRandomColor = true;
  });
  
const colorPicker = document.getElementById('bg-color');
colorPicker.addEventListener('change', () => {
  useRandomColor = false;
});
```

Then we just need to use this value to figure out whether the picked colour is used or whether to use a random value

We also need to make sure we do this for each box

```
// get all the boxes 
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
for (let box of boxes) {
  // add an event listener to each box
  box.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
    // set default value as the current value of the colour picker
    let color = colorPicker.value;

    // Override this with a random colour if needed
    if (useRandomColor){
      let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      color = `#${r.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'}${g.toString(16)}${b.toString(16)}`;
    }

    // Set the background colour of the hovered box
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
};
```

**UPDATE -** *Use padded hex values*

As @enhzflep pointed out, the colour value needs to be exactly either 3 or 6 hex digits, so we need to ensure the generated colour has exactly 6 hex digits.

```
const getColourString = (r, g, b) => {
  return '#' + [r, g, b].map(x => x.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
};
```

This will take our rgb colour components and make sure the value is the correct format.

We will then use this in setting the box background colour

```
e.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

```js
let useRandomColor = false;

function drawGrid(container, col, row) {
  const box = document.createElement('div');
  box.className = 'box';
  box.id = `box${col}${row}`;

  container.appendChild(box);
  return (box);
}


function createBox(container) {
  const grid = document.createElement('div');
  grid.className = 'grid';

  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      drawGrid(grid, i, j);
    }
  }
  container.appendChild(grid);
}

function startupGrid() {
  const game = document.querySelector('#game');
  createBox(game)
}
startupGrid()

// When rgb button is clicked mouseenter random colors and it should ignore color pallet
document.getElementById('rgb')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    useRandomColor = true;
  });
  
const colorPicker = document.getElementById('bg-color');
colorPicker.addEventListener('change', () => {
  useRandomColor = false;
})

  // Wehn color pallet is clicked mouseenter radom colors and it should ignore rbg button
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
for (let box of boxes) {
  box.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
    let color = colorPicker.value;

    if (useRandomColor){
      let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      color = getColourString(r, g, b);
    }

    e.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
};

const getColourString = (r, g, b) => {
  return '#' + [r, g, b].map(x => x.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
};
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  place-items: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  margin: 5rem;
}

.controls {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

button {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}


#game {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  
}

.box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  gap: 1px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Grid</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="color" id="bg-color">
      <button id="rgb">Random Colour</button>
    </div>
     
    <div id="game"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When color pallet is black, if button is clicked initialize ```random color``` when mousehovers on the boxes, and when color pallet is changed to another color it should override the ```random color``` on mousehover

Comment: Does that not happen. Clicking the button sets a random colour which is used when the mouse hovers over the grid to the right. If you pick a specific colour then that colour is used. Are you saying that all the coloured boxes should change to match the color input colour when the color input's value is changed?

Comment: I am saying the it should not only show one color on the box but random colors on all the boxes when mouse hovers over them

Comment: Ah, one moment.

Comment: What if you use r=g=b=15? (#0F0F0F) Answer - you get back #FFF. (15).toString(16) = F.  You need it to return 0F

Comment: See above image the first image is when color pallet is used and the second is when button is clicked, I managed to do that with checkbox from the help i got, but my goal is to do it with button click

Comment: @enhzflep updated to pad hex colour properly

Comment: @callmeog See updated answer